# Serialize self referenced object list to JSON without square brackets

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, serialization

I am writing a `spring-boot` application where my controller should return `JSON`.

My model:

```
public class Category {
    private String name;
    private List<Category> subCategory;
    //getters, setters, constructors 
}
```

Test/data populated for this model:

```
    @Test
    public void testCategory() throws JsonProcessingException {
        Category city1 = new Category("London",null);
        Category city2 = new Category("Leeds",null);
        Category country = new Category("UK",Arrays.asList(city1,city2));
        Category continent = new Category("Europe", Arrays.asList(country));
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        System.out.println( mapper.writeValueAsString(continent));
    }
```

This produces output as:

```
{
  "name" : "Europe",
  "subCategory" : [ {
    "name" : "UK",
    "subCategory" : [ {
      "name" : "London",
      "subCategory" : null
    }, {
      "name" : "Leeds",
      "subCategory" : null
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

Desired output(ignore formatting except each sub category should be indented):

```
   {
     "Europe": {
          "UK": { 
              "London": {},
               "Leeds": {} 
              }
            }
    }
```

This is my original problem.
I tried few things such as `Map<String,Object>` as `subcategory`, it works but it produces output where `London` and `Leeds` are wrapped inside `[]`. I cannot have those in the response to client.

Edit:

If I use Map based approach:

```
    @Test
    public void testCategory2() throws JsonProcessingException {
        Map<String,Object> leeds = Map.of("Leeds",new HashMap<>());
        Map<String,Object> london = Map.of("London",new HashMap<>());
        MultiValuedMap<String, Object> uk = new        HashSetValuedHashMap<>();
        uk.put("UK",london);
        uk.put("UK",leeds);
        Map<String,Object> europe = Map.of("Europe", uk.asMap());
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(europe);
        System.out.println(json);
    }
```

Output:

```
{
  "Europe" : {
    "UK" : [ {
      "London" : { }
    }, {
      "Leeds" : { }
    } ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Your desired output isn't valid JSON. Maybe you forgot a { at the start and a } at the end? If your client really expects something that isn't valid JSON, you won't be able to use Jackson to satisfy it.

Comment: @neofelis, thanks, yes, I was missing. Edited to reflect the correct Json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm not a big fan of the "bunch of maps" approach -- I don't dislike it enough to downvote, but it's... not the most aesthetically pleasing code. You're massaging your values until Jackson does what you want with them given its default settings. You can just tell Jackson what to do with your values instead. That requires some more typing but I find it more elegant; possibly, it's also more understandable/extensible.

First, a note -- both your question and the maps-based answer create an `ObjectMapper` using `new`. Spring Boot gives you an object mapper if you're using spring-starter-json (or something like spring-starter-web which includes it). You can just autowire it. In this answer, I assume that you want to do that, since I don't see why you wouldn't.

On to the problem. You want to turn a Java list into an object; Jackson won't do that by default. In general, if you want Jackson to do something which it can't do by default, you can write a custom (de)serializer. In your case, we want a custom serializer for `Category`s and we *also* want a custom serializer for *lists* of `Category`s. (You can get away with just the second one if you are willing to wrap `Category`s in singleton lists before serializing them, but I don't think I'd want to do that.) So let's write these serializers. They're both pretty easy to write.

```java
public class ListOfCategorySerializer extends StdSerializer<List<Category>> {
    public ListOfCategorySerializer(JavaType t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(List<Category> value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject();

        for (var c: value) {
            gen.writeFieldName(c.getName());
            gen.writeObject(c.getCategories());
        }

        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

and

```java
public class CategorySerializer extends StdSerializer<Category> {
    public CategorySerializer(Class<Category> c) { super(c); }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Category value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject();

        gen.writeFieldName(value.getName());

        // when we're done configuring stuff, the line below will result in
        // Jackson using our ListOfCategorySerializer
        provider.defaultSerializeValue(value.getCategories(), gen);

        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Then, we need to tell Jackson to use them. Normally, you'd do this by just using `@JsonSerialize` on the entity class or its fields, but here you can't do that, because you need to use one serializer for the class and another for one of the class's fields. So you need to write a module. The nice thing here is that you're using Spring Boot, which will automatically register all `Module` beans with the `ObjectMapper` that it gives you.

```java
@Component
public class CategoriesModule extends SimpleModule {
    @Override
    public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
        JavaType t = context.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionLikeType(List.class, Category.class);
        ListOfCategorySerializer ser = new ListOfCategorySerializer(t);
        this.addSerializer(ser);

        this.addSerializer(new CategorySerializer(Category.class));

        super.setupModule(context);
    }
}
```

Now we can, in a class which has an `@Autowired ObjectMapper mapper`, say

```java
var london = new Category("London", Arrays.asList(new Category[] {}));
var leeds = new Category("Leeds", Arrays.asList(new Category[] {}));
var uk = new Category("UK", Arrays.asList(new Category[] {london, leeds}));
var europe = new Category("Europe", Arrays.asList(new Category[] {uk}));

var s = mapper.writeValueAsString(europe);
```

and `s` will contain exactly your expected output. Well, almost exactly; it won't contain any sort of padding. You know one way to get the padding -- using `ObjectMapper.enable` -- but since you're using Spring Boot, a better way is to just put `spring.jackson.serialization.indent-output=true` into your `application.properties`.

Comment: Wow, thank you! I love this. The Map based approach though it worked, was iffy. Much cleaner and maintainable approach. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This will produce what you want it to be

```
  @Test
    public void testCategory2() throws JsonProcessingException {
        Map<String,Object> ukNestedField = new HashMap<>();
        ukNestedField.put("Leeds", new HashMap<String, Object>());
        ukNestedField.put("London", new HashMap<String, Object>());

        Map<String,Object> franceNestedField = new HashMap<>();

        Map<String, Map<String, Object>> outer = new HashMap<>();
        outer.put("UK",ukNestedField );
        outer.put("FR",franceNestedField );

        Map<String,Object> europe = Map.of("Europe", outer.asMap());
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(europe);
        System.out.println(json);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am pretty sure it can be done, even with dynamic fields like I have.

Comment: @IanMcGrath for sure it can be done with manual serialization, the point I want to make is that it does not make sense as it is.

Comment: and for sure cannot be done with a staticaly defined Java object. You have to dynamicaly create the json response . Check how you can do it dynamically https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-node-tree-model

Comment: Yep, it does not. The client expects it to be this way, unortunately. I've been pulling my hair for the past few hours about this. Any idea how should I go about with/without manual serialization. I can share code where I used Map based approach if it helps.

Comment: Yes, has to be dynamic. Yes, I expect other countries ..

Comment: I edited question to show my Map based approach and the output. I am happy to write custom serialization if needed. Do you think you can help with that?

Comment: thank you, I am not able to write code for say France (with no cities) inside Europe, along with existing UK object. Could you please help with that? I will accept your answer.

Comment: @IanMcGrath you can always upvote as well for the provided help ;)